# SQL join not not real results

Tags: sql

I have a database with some tables and I want to retrieve from a user the last 8 tee of user that I follow:
This is my table:
Table users:

```
- id
- name
- surname
- created
- modified

2 | Caesar | Surname1 
3 | Albert | Surname2
4 | Paul   | Surname3
5 | Nicol  | Surname4
```

Table tee

```
- id
- name
- user_id

1 | first | 3
2 | second | 3
3 | third | 4
4 | fourth | 4
5 | fifth | 5
6 | sixth | 5
7 | seventh | 5
```

table user_follow

```
- id 
- user_follower_id //the user that decide to follo someone
- user_followed_id //the user that I decide to follow

1 | 2 | 3
2 | 2 | 5
```

I expect to retrieve this tee with its creator because my id is 2 (I'm Caesar for example):

```
1 | first | 3
2 | second | 3
5 | fifth | 5
6 | sixth | 5
7 | seventh | 5
```

For example if I user that I follow have created 4 tee another that I follow 1, another 2, I think that I can retrieve all this tee if are the last inserted in all sites because are created from user that I follow.
**But I retrieve only one tee of an user**

This is my query:

```
SELECT *, `tee`.`id` as id, `tee`.`created` as created, `users`.`id` as user_id, `users`.`created` as user_created 
FROM (`tee`) 
LEFT JOIN `users` 
ON `users`.`id` = `tee`.`user_id` 
LEFT JOIN `user_follow` ON `tee`.`user_id` = `user_follow`.`user_followed_id` 
WHERE `tee`.`id` != '41' AND 
      `tee`.`id` != '11' AND
      `tee`.`id` != '13' AND
      `tee`.`id` != '20' AND
      `tee`.`id` != '14' AND 
      `tee`.`id` != '35' AND
      `tee`.`id` != '31' AND
      `tee`.`id` != '36' AND
      `user_follow`.`user_follower_id` = '2' 
ORDER BY `tee`.`created` desc LIMIT 8
```

I have added 8 tee id that I don't want to retrieve because are "special".

Why this query doesn't work?
I think the problem is in left join or I have to make other thing to retreve this results.

Thanks

Comment: *Doesn't work* meaning...?

Comment: I have write that I retrieve only one tee (row) instead of multiple because I have more tee inserted from my follower

Comment: Can you post sample data and desired results -- nothing terribly wrong with your query.  You could use `NOT IN` instead of all those `AND` statements.  Also, no need to use an `OUTER JOIN` on the user_follow table since you include that table in your `WHERE` criteria.  But your query should run...

Comment: sorry for asking this, but I have seen people that had this misunderstanding: do you use SQL directly in a db query tool, or do you use another language to view the result? for example in php, using the default db methods, you need to **loop** over the result to get all lines

Comment: Added an example @sgeddes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your query -- I have updated the syntax to use `INNER JOINs` and to use `NOT IN` though:

```
SELECT *, 
    `tee`.`id` as id, `tee`.`created` as created, `users`.`id` as user_id, `users`.`created` as user_created 
FROM `tee`
    JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `tee`.`user_id` 
    JOIN `user_follow` ON `tee`.`user_id` = `user_follow`.`user_followed_id` 
WHERE `tee`.`id` NOT IN (41,11,13,20,14,35,31,36) 
    AND `user_follow`.`user_follower_id` = '2' 
ORDER BY `tee`.`created` desc 
LIMIT 8
```

- [Condensed SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8561e6/4)

Answer (score 0):

you can use Not In ('41','11',...) instead of  `tee`.`id` != '41' AND `tee`.`id` != '11'.....

Comment: This is not the problem of the question

Answer (score 0):

Use a UNION clause. First select your tees then select the tees from people you follow.

Comment: Can you make an example? Please

Comment: Honestly, I don't have time. Try it yourself and if it doesn't work I'll check it.